# Should we flag old harassments in answers/comments?

Tags: discussion, flags

You see... I'm a really big fan of the updated [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) and I think it's reinforced in a very necessary moment (could have been earlier, but great anyway). But now I'm divided.

Usually (generally) I tend to follow this idea that a something is only valid from the moment it was created and not backwards. But sometimes I'm scrolling through old answers and there are plenty of cases where people were just being entirely rude without any necessity for doing so. Even the ones answering sometimes.

So... would it be acceptable to flag an answer/comment sometimes from 5 years ago as harassment?

Comment: I just marked a comment from a few years back as being rude. My worry is that the people that review the flags might be more lenient on older comments- but I hope that isn't the case

Comment: If it's harassment now, it was harassment then.  What sort of comment are you thinking about where it might have been acceptable?

Comment: @chevybow While I have no basis for this assumption, I suspect most mods don't even look at the date of the comment when evaluating the flag, at least not unless the flag message indicates that it's somehow relevant.

Comment: I wonder why my question was downvoted... well, I agree. But even having the rules it wasn't being used or reinforced as it is now. I came through a question like that earlier at work but I can't find it now, if I do, I will mark it down here.

Comment: @Rafael Harassment has always been flagged and deleted.  SO is up there in terms of most effectively moderated sites I've ever used in my my life.  Over the many years I've been on here it's done a better job of removing insulting or abusive content faster than any other site I've ever been on.  Saying that it was accepted until a few days ago is rather insulting to all of the people that have spent as much time and effort as they have doing such a good job to remove inappropriate content.

Comment: Much indeed Servy, will adapt my comment for not sounding like that. Thank you for the head's up.

Comment: Rafael it's possible you got downvoted since the way you posted this it seems you may intend to use the CoC as a weapon to bash other people with. I didn't downvote or get that this is what you meant but it's definitely a possible interpretation of how you phrased your question. And some people aren't hot at that idea

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Harassment has never been acceptable.  It didn't just suddenly become no okay.

The (relevant) rules are no different from what they've always been, they were just re-worded to make them clearer for people.

That said, hypothetically, if there were a rule that changed what's appropriate to post on the site, it applies to everything on the site, not just things posted after the rule changed.

Comment: Great to know! Though I don't see much use in linking the code of conduct for someone that made a tough comment 5-6 years ago, flagging will have to do.

Comment: @Rafael There's no use in linking the code of conduct ever, really.